# Advanced Tweepy Search User Queries, and Their Results?

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy

I am running tweepy and trying to run an advanced query through the "search_users" api. I am noticing a big difference in the search results even if the exact query is passed from the api compared to the web people search on twitter. Any thoughts?

Example

```
query = 'mustang AND near:"New Haven" AND within:15mi'
tweepy.search_users(q=query)
```

Is there a difference? Is there another API call I should look at?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some research I have discovered that the "USER SEARCH" does not currently support advanced search parameters. This is unfortunate. If this changes I will come back and update this answer.